# Python: set x tick specifically for bars in subplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I want to analyze the performance of four tools on running several programs.And one subplot is the results of one tool on all programs. The results should look like this:
[image]

I use for loops to iterate the programs list and plot one part each time as following:

[image]

But the plots appear like a single one and I cannot separate their x ticks by using `axis.set_xticks()`. It seems this function has no effect.

Do I use the correct function to set the x ticks? Or how should I make this plot?

**`draw_hist_query()` may be the most important function for my question**

Data sample:

```
boolector,ppbv,stp,z3
0.05349588394165039,0.015434503555297852,0.028127193450927734,0.11303281784057617
0.0027561187744140625,0.004331827163696289,0.007134914398193359,0.016040563583374023
0.003190755844116211,0.005587577819824219,0.002897500991821289,0.013916015625
0.009758472442626953,0.02006363868713379,0.0031282901763916016,0.011539697647094727
0.057138681411743164,0.012826681137084961,0.030836820602416992,0.0217435359954834
```

Code:

```
index = range(len(solvers))
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4)
solvers = ['z3', 'stp', 'boolector', 'ppbv']
colors = ['g', 'c', 'b', 'r', 'y', 'orange', 'grey']
ticks = [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
width=0.2

# program entry
def all_time_query(path):
    csv = xxx.csv # the array of data to be analyzed, one csv for one program
    for axis in axes:
        axis.set_xticks(range(len(csv)))
    for c in csv:
        multi_time_query(c) # draw the bar pair for c, which shows the upper image for one program on four tools


def multi_time_query(csv):
    data = pd.read_csv(csv)
    for solver in solvers: # the four tools
        bin = index[solvers.index(solver)]
        hist_t_query(data, solver, ax=axes[bin]) # details to draw the bar pair, uses dataframe.plot.bar



def hist_t_query(data, solver, ax):
    solver_data = pd.DataFrame(data).as_matrix(columns=[solver])
    # draw one bar for demo
    draw_hist_query(pd.DataFrame(solver_data), ax)


# left of bar pair, the right one is similar
def draw_hist_query(df, ax):
    count = []
    for i in range(len(ticks)):
        count.append(df[df < ticks[i]].count())
        color = stat.colors[i]
        if i == 0:
            count[i].plot.bar(ax=ax, color=color, width=width, position=0)
        else:
            (count[i] - count[i - 1]).plot.bar(bottom=count[i - 1],
                                               ax=ax, color=color, width=width, position=0)
```

Comment: can you add some code ? Do you use subplots? If so then you can adjust them with subplots_adjust http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust

Comment: @ KacperWolkowski added some code

Comment: I think you need to show `hist_t_query` as well (in particular the part where you call `dataframe.plot.bar`), otherwise it's hard to know what's going on.

Comment: @ThomasKühn more code added, thanks!

Comment: @YushanZhang I think your problem is with your `plot` command. As you plot each data pair separately, they just get stacked. I had a quick look at the documentation (the command is quite different from `matplotlib's` `bar` command), and `pandas.DataFrame.plot` has two keywords that might help: one is `x` and one is `xticks`. I would guess that by setting one of them 'manually', you could get rid of your problem.

Comment: Let me just mention the following: If you create a [mcve] of the issue with some data hardcoded in the code, such that people are able to reproduce the issue, chances are high that your problem gets solved within some hours here on SO. If you don't supply such a [mcve], this conversation may go on forever and you may receive arbitrarily unrelated answers to your question as seen below.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you! Actually I think draw_hist_query() is the only function important in my question.

Comment: It may be the only function responsible for the issue, yes. So the idea would be to create a dataframe in the code, such that the code is runnable and reproduces the issue, which in turn would allow people to come up with a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem:
[image]

What I thought wrongly before is about subplots. I wanted to add another bar pair of in a subplot after one pair is already there. **However, one subplots should be plotted together(at once), and shouldn't be separated.** In my case, the bars for one subplot should appear together and only four times is needed to plot all the subplots.

Here is my new version of code:

```
def time_query_project(path):
    fig, axis = plt.subplots(nrows=4)
    csv = sio.find_csv(path)
    data = {}

    for solver in solvers:
        for c in csv:
            df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(c), columns=[solver])
            data.update({get_name(c): df.to_dict()[solver]})
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
        ax = axis[solvers.index(solver)]
        ax.set_ylabel(solver)
        hist_t_query(df, ax)


def hist_t_query(data, solver, ax):
    solver_data = pd.DataFrame(data).as_matrix(columns=[solver])
    # draw one bar for demo
    draw_hist_query(pd.DataFrame(solver_data), ax)


# left of bar pair, the right one is similar
def draw_hist_query(df, ax):
    count = []
    for i in range(len(ticks)):
        count.append(df[df < ticks[i]].count())
        color = stat.colors[i]
        if i == 0:
            count[i].plot.bar(ax=ax, color=color, width=width, position=0)
        else:
            (count[i] - count[i - 1]).plot.bar(bottom=count[i - 1],
                                               ax=ax, color=color, width=width, position=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you have few options. You can use `plt.tight_layout()` and it will everything automatically or you can use the `plt.subplot_adjust()` and specify each parameter by yourself.
As you can see in documentation, the signature is like that:

```
subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)
```

and also if you will go to the interactive window, you have the option to adjust the parameters there, and you can see how your graph will change with each parameter

[image]

And then you can call subplot_adjust with whatever is best for you.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Actually my problem is on **subplots**, I solved this by myself. If you're interested please see my answer. Thank you all the same :)